# How do I install the openGL ES library on Android Studios?

Tags: java, android-studio

I need to install the OpenGL ES library into android studios for game programming. Is it going to install somehow?

Comment: Unless you know how to use OpenGL this is going to be a long and painful road to go down. Have you considered using something like Unity, Unreal, or Ogre3D instead as a foundation? There's a variety of other developer kits that are optimized around certain kinds of games as well.

Comment: Up to you as to what tools you use, but be aware OpenGL ES is about as low-level as you can get and there's a lot of work you'll have to do to get even the most basic of things on screen. A book like [http://www.gameenginebook.com](http://www.gameenginebook.com) helps outline the work involved when starting from scratch. Installing OpenGL may not be easy, but it's an example of the road ahead. Just an advisory! I'd check if it wasn't already installed as part of that SDK.

Comment: I don't have OpenGL as part of SDK

Comment: Time to go grab it, then.